# how can I delete the invisible wireframe that is inside the mesh?

Tags: mesh, wireframe

how can I delete the invisible wireframe that is inside the mesh?  i tried that with join and boolean.
[image]

Comment: i'm not sure to understand, if you boolean there won't be anymore mesh where the 2 spheres intersect

Comment: I have now tried again with boolean and it worked. But this was only an example picture. How do I proceed if I have, for example, 50 meshes nested inside each other? I thought there should be an easier way to remove all invisible edges and vertices. In the end this is a sculpture which I then create a wireframe - that's why I want to remove them, because they would then be visible.

Comment: do you mean that you don't want to see the inner vertices when you are in Wireframe display mode?

Comment: Actually what we see is the sphere that is used as boolean object, what you could do is select it and go into the Object panel > Viewport Display > Display As > Bounds

Comment: thanks! tried that with remesh, and it works now.